# How do I add an input field after an element was created with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add an input field to a created element. This is my code.

```
var Images_to_beuploaded_cont = document.getElementById("Images_to_beuploaded_cont");

  var carCont = document.createElement('div');
  carCont.className += "multipleImageAdding";

  Images_to_beuploaded_cont.insertBefore(carCont, Images_to_beuploaded_cont.firstChild);
```

So, the code above adds the following

```
<div id="multipleImageAdding"></div>
```

What I want to do is the code below.

```
<div id="multipleImageAdding">
   <input type="text" name="fname">
</div>
```

Is this even possible? to add an element to another after it was created?

Comment: Of course, yes. Just `appendChild` your input to div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this even possible? to add an element to another after it was created?

Yes, you could add the `input` element before or after appending the parent container element.

After creating the `input` element and adding the desired `type` and `name` attributes, just use the [`appendChild()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'text';
input.name = 'fname';

carCont.appendChild(input);
```

Snippet:

```js
var Images_to_beuploaded_cont = document.getElementById("Images_to_beuploaded_cont");

var carCont = document.createElement('div');
carCont.className += "multipleImageAdding";

var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'text';
input.name = 'fname';

carCont.appendChild(input);

Images_to_beuploaded_cont.insertBefore(carCont, Images_to_beuploaded_cont.firstChild);
```

```html
<div id="Images_to_beuploaded_cont"></div>
```

Comment: this worked like a charm. Now, all I will have to figure out is how to add it at the bottom of the div if I even add another element inside that div. Thanks mate.